# bgiframe plugin causes error in IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, bgiframe

The uiquery plugin bgiframe (version 2.1.1) causes the following java script error in Internet Explorer 9:

```
jquery.bgiframe.js, line 94 character 5
```

My menu does not work any more, I hope the reason is this error.

Any ideas?

ADDED:

The line in jquery.bgiframe.js is:

```
this.insertBefore( document.createElement(html), this.firstChild );
```

and the error sais:

```
SCRIPT5022: DOM Exception: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR (5)
```

Comment: and what is on this line?  you can use IE developer tools to get this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After some more research I found a solution myself on the bgiframe site:

I downloaded version 2.1.3-pre at

https://github.com/brandonaaron/bgiframe/blob/master/jquery.bgiframe.js

and this solved the problem.

Answer (score 12):

In the plugin code for bgiframe version 2.1.1 was doing a regex search for "6.0" but it needs to search for "MSIE 6.0". Tillito has found the correct source.

In the bgiframe code look for:

`if($.browser.msie&&/6.0/.test(navigator.userAgent)`

Change to:

`if($.browser.msie && /msie 6\.0/i.test(navigator.userAgent)`

OR just get the source here: https://github.com/brandonaaron/bgiframe/blob/master/jquery.bgiframe.js

Answer (score 1):

```
var parent = document.createElement("div");
parent.innerHTML = html;
this.insertBefore( parent, this.firstChild );
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below tag after head tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```