# jQueryUI Autocomplete function not properly working on IE9

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using this snippet of code for my `jQueryUI Autocomplete` function on my site,

```
$( "#find" ).autocomplete({
            minLength: 1,
            source: function(request, response) {
                        var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(locations, request.term);
                        response(results.slice(0, 10));
                    },
            focus: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#find" ).val( ui.item.value );
                return false;
            },
            appendTo: "#results",
            open: function(){
                var position = $("#results").position(),
                                left = position.left, top = position.top;

                        $("#results > ul").css({left: (left + 15) + "px",
                                                                top: (top + 30) + "px", width: (206) + "px" });
            },

            select: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#find" ).val( ui.item.value );
                $(":header.title").html(ui.item.value);
                var new_url = ui.item.href; // instead of adding 'statistics', by using location.hash, it wont be necessary unlike using pushState()
                location.hash = new_url;
                return false;
            }
        })
        .data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
            return $( "<li></li>" )
                .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                .append( "<a>" + item.label + "<br />" + item.desc + "</a>" )
                .appendTo( ul );
        };
```

Actually this works perfectly fine on `Firefox` and `Chrome`, it behaves just like what it exactly behaves on the sample given [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/custom-data.html), I just merely copied and modified it according to what I wanted. But on `IE9`, the `item.desc` which shows up on other browsers is not visible on `IE9`. I think the code to start with fixing is the last part, the part which appends the suggestions of the autocomplete. Can someone help me out here? Cheers!

Comment: have you looked for errors in the console? I am currently using the exact same control and didn't have any problems in IE9 on Win7, but there could be some other code that is causing an error

Comment: @Qpirate only this error, `SCRIPT5022: DOM Exception: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR (5) 
jquery.bgiframe.min.js?v2, line 10 character 978` is on my IE9, but this error is not on firefox and chrome. Do you think this is the reason why it wont work?

Comment: It could be depending on when you add your JS file for the JQueryUI import. have a look here they seemed to have solved it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424526/bgiframe-plugin-causes-error-in-ie9

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade `bgiframe.min.js` to a later version (3.0 works fine)
https://github.com/brandonaaron/bgiframe

Answer (score 0):

Create a new css class to override the existing jquery ui autocomplete "position":"absolute"

```
.ui-autocompelte{
"position": "absolute"
....
....
}
```

New CSS Class

```
.ui-autocomplete-ie9-fix { position: relative !important; }
```

and apply this css class after 
$("#find").autocompelte({ 
........
.......
});

```
if (!$.browser.msie || ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version != 9)) {
        $("ul.ui-autocomplete").addClass("ui-autocomplete-ie9-fix");
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Add below tag after head tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```